# Send content over multiple requests [ FastAPI & Deta ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, serverless

I recently got to know about deta (https://www.deta.sh/) and using there services (deta drive) i tried to make a cdn with fastapi. The issue is that they restricted the payload to 5.5 mb (manually uploading from their site works) . So, whenever i try to upload or get a image from drive using fastapi (UploadFile & StreamingResponse) i get 413 ( Request entity too large) or 502 ( when streaming the file).

Related code can be found here - https://docs.deta.sh/docs/drive/py_tutorial

Is there any way to bypass it? Like send via multiple requests or something like that?

Comment: You can compress and bin your large files into several chunks and rebuild them.

Comment: @Irfanuddin can you show some code related to it or the modules which can be used?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/filesplit/ or if you are looking to compress https://pypi.org/project/split-file-reader/